# How can I resolve 'Operation returned an invalid status code NotFound' error when using embedded token in Power BI?

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to use the embedded token in a powerBI report but i had a not found exception

I'm trying to use the embedded token in a powerBI, i already create the app registration, the APi permissions were granted by the azure admin, i created a embedded capacity for test, but i always have this exception

`Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound' at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.<GenerateTokenInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__32.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.<GenerateTokenInGroupAsync>d__87.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GenerateTokenInGroup(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters) at EmbedAPISample.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Testes de Codigo\CSharp\PowerBI\Token\Embed-API-Sample\EmbedAPISample\Program.cs:line 53`

The code i'm using is:

```
class Program
    {
        private static bool useEmbedToken = true;
        private static bool useRLS = false;

        private static string authorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/"; 
        private static string resourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
        private static string apiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/";

        private static string tenantId = "tenant id";
        private static Guid groupId = Guid.Parse("group id");
        
        private static Guid reportId = Guid.Parse("report id");
        private static Guid datasetId = Guid.Parse("data set id"); 

        // **** Update the Client ID and Secret within Secrets.cs ****

        private static ClientCredential credential = null;
        private static AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        private static TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                // Create a user password cradentials.
                credential = new ClientCredential(Secrets.ClientID, Secrets.ClientSecret);

                // Authenticate using created credentials
                Authorize().Wait();

                using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), tokenCredentials))
                {

                    #region Embed Token
                    EmbedToken embedToken = null;


                    if (useEmbedToken && !useRLS)
                    {
                        // **** Without RLS ****
                        embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupId, reportId,
                        new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View", datasetId: datasetId.ToString())) ;
                        //string lala = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View", datasetId: datasetId.ToString()).;


                        //Console.WriteLine(lala);
                    }
                    else if(useEmbedToken && useRLS)
                    {
```

have more code but nothing about the token creation, i used this sample from guy in a cube repository but not worked for me..

the repository: https://github.com/guyinacube/Embed-API-Sample

Answer (score 0):

Able to generate the embed token using the same repository and not facing any such error.

Can you please verify:

1. If you have all the required permission.
2. Check if the values entered
   for tenantId, reportId, groupId and datasetId are correct.